# Unable to pass object as parameter to Angular 5 get request

Tags: c#, angular, angular5, angular-httpclient

I'm working on a project using Angular 5 and C# WebAPI's. I'm very comfortable working in these environments.

I'm stuck at an Angular HTTP GET request. I'm trying to send a GET request with comprised of a JSON Object and 2 string variables (total 3 items) to my web api. I'm able to receive the 2 string values in my c# controller, but not able to receive the JSON object in my c# controller.

Please see the details below:

I'm having a JSON object:

```
{
  "onlineAdmissionFilterArray": [
    {
      "Index": 1,
      "Column": "Time",
      "DataType": "VALUE",
      "ComparisionValue": "LESS THAN",
      "FilterValue": "1",
      "Operator": "AND"
    },
    {
      "Index": 2,
      "Column": "Time",
      "DataType": "VALUE",
      "ComparisionValue": "GREATER THAN EQUAL TO",
      "FilterValue": "3",
      "Operator": "--"
    }
  ],
  "admissionFileName": "APRIL-18-BATCH 01-20180407182256.XLS",
  "_loggedInUserGUID": "490253d0-79f6-4aed-96a9-5a041375d84c"
}
```

which I am seeking to pass to my C# WebAPI controller which is:
*(Pls excuse the return type from webapi function, my concern is with the parameters it has)*

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("FilterOnlineAdmissionStudents")]
public string FilterOnlineAdmissionStudents(List<OnlineAdmissionFilterVM> onlineAdmissionFilterArray, string admissionFileName, string _loggedInUserGUID)
{
    return string.Empty;
}
```

The C# Model object for "**OnlineAdmissionFilterVM**" is:

```
public class OnlineAdmissionFilterVM
{
    public string Column { get; set; }
    public string ComparisionValues { get; set; }
    public string DataType { get; set; }
    public string FilterValue { get; set; }
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public string Operator { get; set; }
}
```

and my Angular HTTP GET request code is:

```
  public FilterOnlineAdmissionStudents(
    onlineAdmissionFilterArray: OnlineAdmissionFilter[],
    admissionFileName: string,
    _loggedInUserGUID: string,
    httpHeaders: HttpHeaders
  ) {
    return this.httpClient.get(this.apiUrl + 'api/admission/online/FilterOnlineAdmissionStudents',
      {
        headers: httpHeaders,
        params: new HttpParams()
          .set('onlineAdmissionFilterArray', 'test')
          .set('admissionFileName', admissionFileName)
          .set('_loggedInUserGUID', _loggedInUserGUID)
      }
    );
  }
```

I believe I'm doing some silly mistake, or my code format is incorrect.
Can any one assist me?

Comment: You can not send JSON object as GET request parameter. Use POST for that.

Comment: As mentioned, GET requests do not have an http body. You can only send data via the URL.

Comment: Thanks for your responses guys, I've solved this issue by POST. Didn't knew that GET doesn't have 'http body'.